# How to make a FlowLayoutPanel Resizable at runtime?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this [GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNWLt.png) for my Winform application with 2 FlowLayoutPanels Docked top and right respectively.

Right now I can only give them a fixed size which cannot be changed by user at run time but I want to make these panel Resizable while the application is running.
I've tried **BorderStyle** Property but only available options are **Fixed3D** and **FixedSingle** which are obviously cannot be resized due to their ***Fixed!*** behaviour.

I've already gone through the documentation at [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/flowlayoutpanel-control-windows-forms) but couldn't find anything.

I want to know if I can make them resizable programmatically?

Comment: The `BorderStyle` property has nothing to do with resizing. It's to draw a border around the controls bounds to visualize them. When using `Dock` or `Anchor` you can control the resizing behaviour of a control relatively to their parent, all the way up to the form. Also a `TableLayoutPanel` could help you.

Comment: Ohh! I get your point, I thought it is somewhat related as if you make the border style fixed, you cannot resize them by dragging the borders.